# Not able to set JAVA_HOME for hadoop using cygwin

Tags: hadoop, cygwin, java-home

I am trying to set `JAVA_HOME` in `env.sh` in hadoop. I am using cygwin on Windows 7.
I have edited the `env.sh` as :

```
export JAVA_HOME= "/cygdrive/C/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26"
```

In environment variables I have set `JAVA_HOM`E as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26`

And the path as `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;c:\cygwin\bin;c:\cygwin\usr\sbin`

But still I am getting these errors.

```
/cygdrive/d/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found

/cygdrive/d/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 7: $'\r': command not found

': not a valid identifierlibexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 9: export: 

`/cygdrive/C/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26


/cygdrive/d/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 12: $'\r': command not found

/cygdrive/d/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 41: $'\r': command not found


/cygdrive/d/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 46: $'\r': command not found


/cygdrive/d/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 52: $'\r': command not found


/cygdrive/d/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 55: $'\r': command not found


Error: JAVA_HOME is not set.
```

I have checked everything possible on this website but still facing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 export JAVA_HOME="C:/PROGRA~2/Java/jdk1.6.0_03"
```

#for 32 bit Java arch

Use

```
  export  export JAVA_HOME="C:/PROGRA~1/Java/jdk1.6.0_03"
```

#for 64 bit Java arch

This will fix your problem... The answer I am giving is pretty late but it will help others who are beginners facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

use C:\"Program Files"\Java\jdk1.6.0_26 instead, that should solve the java problem.